# Different output after decode and encode data (base64)

Tags: python, base64

If i run:

```
import base64
data = open('1.dat', 'rb').read()
decoded = base64.b64decode(data)
encoded = base64.b64encode(decoded)
data == encoded
```

I get "False" as result?
How to decode/encode to get the original result?

Comment: in my file "1.dat" ist a base64 encoded string

Comment: There is some flexibility in the way base64 is encoded, for example the insertion of newlines. There's no requirement or expectation that two encodings will be identical.

Comment: Try using `data.strip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 is not base64 unfortunately. There may be differences in the implementations. Some implementation for example insert line breaks every 76 characters when encoding, some don't.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `b64encode()` the data before you `b64decode()` it:

```
>>> import base64
>>> data = b"qwertzuiop"
>>> encoded = base64.b64encode(data)
>>> decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
>>> data == decoded
True
```

If your input file is already base64, you need to `b64decode()` it first, not encode. So your code should be this:

```
import base64
data = open('1.dat', 'rb').read()  # base64 encoded string
decoded = base64.b64decode(data)
encoded = base64.b64encode(decoded)
data == encoded
```

If you are getting False as a result, your `data` is Base64 encoded differently than what the `base64` module does.

Comment: @spitzbuaamy Then it means that the base64 in your 1.dat is different from the one that the `base64` module in python uses. How did you create the 1.dat file?

Answer (score 0):

There is some flexibility in the way base64 is encoded, for example the insertion of newlines. There may also be some alternate characters which the [`base64` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) allows you to specify when encoding and decoding. It's up to you to make sure the proper alternate characters are specified, but otherwise it's easy to compare two strings while ignoring any newlines or whitespace:

```
''.join(data.split()) == ''.join(encoded.split())
```